# KQL - Display affected resources

Tags: azure, kql

I currently have a query which displays recommendation display name and subscription name. I would like to display the information under property resourceDetails like ResourceName and ResourceID.Is this possible?

```
securityresources
| where type == "microsoft.security/assessments"`
| extend name = properties.displayName`
| extend resourceDetails = properties.resourceDetails`
| where name contains "Machines should have a vulnerability assessment solution"`
| join kind=leftouter  ( `
  `  resourcecontainers`
        `| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"`
        `| extend resolvedSubId = tostring(split(id, '/', 2)[0]), subscriptionName = name`
        `| project resolvedSubId, subscriptionName`
) on $left.subscriptionId == $right.resolvedSubId`
| project name, resourceDetails, subscriptionName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to display the information under property resourceDetails like ResourceName and ResourceID.Is this possible?

Yes, you can use below **`KQL Query`** (modified your query a bit):

```
securityresources
| where type == "microsoft.security/assessments" 
| extend name = properties.displayName 
| extend resourceDetails = properties.resourceDetails 
| where name contains "Machines should have a vulnerability assessment solution" 
| join kind=leftouter (   resourcecontainers | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions" 
| extend resolvedSubId = tostring(split(id, '/', 2)[0]), subscriptionName = name | project resolvedSubId, subscriptionName ) on $left.subscriptionId == $right.resolvedSubId 
| project name, resourceDetails, subscriptionName
| extend resourname= parse_json(resourceDetails)
| project name,subscriptionName,ResourceName=resourname.ResourceName, ResourceID=resourname.ResourceId
```

**`Output:`**

[image]